Algorithm to turn a blockcipher into a PRP for any (large) group size
Which algorithm is most efficient to turn a 128 bit block cipher and create a PRP for any group size, e.g. for values in a range $[0..n)$ where $n$ isn't necessarily a an exponent of two? I'm interested in larger group sizes than e.g. $2^{16}$, the maximum radix used for FF1 and FF3.
Notes:

The algorithm should have a security bound equal to or better than FF3 (assuming FF3 is used with a secure number of values of a particular radix).
Efficiency should be based on the average number of executions of the block cipher, while having a negligible chance of getting into an untannable worst case scenario.
Preferably the algorithm should not be too hard to implement; pointers to (pseudo-) code of the algorithm would be greatly appreciated.


I have read some articles about shuffling and I'm presuming an answer will be in that direction. [edit: that only seems to work for small domains, not larger ones as the default implementation is memory intensive], but I'm not sure about what is currently considered most efficient, while secure. And maybe there is something better out there by now.

This doesn't exactly answer the question since it does not just use block ciphers... But I mention this FPE construction called FAST (https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1171). It uses AES to generate some randomness, but the core of it is Substitution permutation networks based on random SBOXes.

Ah, already an intersting comment - maybe I should not have required only a 128 bit block cipher. I'm not sure if it fits the purpose though, their recommended security parameters indicate radix $a \geq 4$ and message size $l \geq 2$. Their example is using radix 10, i.e. a decimal number. I don't see any maximum for $a$ but in principle $l \geq 2$ breaks my requirements.

Generic solutions: EME or similar wide-block mode if you need wide blocks, Luby-Rackoff if you want narrower blocks. To get from nearest power of two to n, just iterate the block cipher until the result is below n. Not cheap, maybe, but secure and no real thinking needed.

@K.G. Yeah, I'm starting to gravitate to that solution as well. You'll need to be very unlucky if that results in a humongous amount of calls to the block cipher, but it's probably not something for embedded devices :)
